# Run an mpi application in docker

Tags: docker

I'm playing with docker and I wanted to be able to launch an mpi application in it.

I'm using ubuntu:latest as base image and  I have installed the needed tools to compile my program and link it with mpi.

When I launch the program using mpirun, I get these warnings:

```
[c1dab84c3fac:10417] [[INVALID],INVALID] ORTE_ERROR_LOG: Not found in file ess_hnp_module.c at line 170
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
It looks like orte_init failed for some reason; your parallel process is
likely to abort.  There are many reasons that a parallel process can
fail during orte_init; some of which are due to configuration or
environment problems.  This failure appears to be an internal failure;
here's some additional information (which may only be relevant to an
Open MPI developer):

orte_plm_base_select failed
  --> Returned value Not found (-13) instead of ORTE_SUCCESS
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
[c1dab84c3fac:10417] [[INVALID],INVALID] ORTE_ERROR_LOG: Not found in file runtime/orte_init.c at line 128
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
It looks like orte_init failed for some reason; your parallel process is
likely to abort.  There are many reasons that a parallel process can
fail during orte_init; some of which are due to configuration or
environment problems.  This failure appears to be an internal failure;
here's some additional information (which may only be relevant to an
Open MPI developer):

orte_ess_set_name failed
  --> Returned value Not found (-13) instead of ORTE_SUCCESS
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
[c1dab84c3fac:10417] [[INVALID],INVALID] ORTE_ERROR_LOG: Not found in file orterun.c at line 694
```

If I run the same program in a normal ubuntu (same version), it runs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Docker container is not like normal Ubuntu. The default Ubuntu container has allot of basic things missing (example: init, ssh daemon, cron)

Usually I use phusion base-image docker, goto like below to find out more about some basic issues in default Ubuntu docker and how those issues can be resolved.

http://phusion.github.io/baseimage-docker/

Answer (score 12):

I have met this problem recently.
Install ssh package will fix this issue.

Comment: I think if you explained the reason and the mechanism could give you even upvotes.

Comment: @peterh Sorry, I did not look into much details but this thread inspires me that it's an issue with ssh: http://www.open-mpi.org/community/lists/users/2010/07/13503.php

Comment: this makes sense, as mpi needs something to communicate (rsh, ssh other)

Comment: I confirm that it sill works today :)